# Find the projection T on W along U using span

Tags: linear-algebra, projection

The question is:
Consider the following subspaces of R2:
U = Span [1, 2]^T and W = Span [1, −1]^T
Find the projection T on W along U

I understand that KerT=U and imT=W, but I am unsure how it would apply to this. Would it just be W since KerT=U or is this an over reach? I am also unsure of how to compute T without knowing what T is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point $P = [x, y]^T$ can be written as a linear combination of $U$ and $W$

$ P = c_1 U + c_2 W $

We need to find $c_2$ as a function of $P$.  Now,

$ P = [ U , W ] \begin{bmatrix} c_1 \\ c_2 \end{bmatrix} $

Therefore

$ \begin{bmatrix} c_1 \\ c_2 \end{bmatrix} = [U, W]^{-1} P $

And the finally, the projection is

$ Q = \text{Proj}( P ) = c_2 W = W [0, 1] [U, W]^{-1} P = T P  $

To find $T$ explicitly for the given $U$ and $W$,

$ [U, W] = \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 1 \\ 2 && - 1 \end{bmatrix}$

$ [U, W]^{-1} = -\dfrac{1}{3} \begin{bmatrix} -1 && -1 \\ -2 && 1 \end{bmatrix}$

Hence,

$ T = -\dfrac{1}{3} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0 && 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} -1 && -1 \\ -2 && 1 \end{bmatrix} $

$ T = - \dfrac{1}{3} \begin{bmatrix} 0 && 1 \\ 0 && -1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} -1 && -1 \\ -2 && 1 \end{bmatrix} = -\dfrac{1}{3} \begin{bmatrix} -2 && 1 \\ 2 && -1 \end{bmatrix} $